# How to make an empty bytes32 variable in vyper

Tags: vyper

How do I make an empty `bytes32` variable in vyper?

```py
@external
def return_empty() -> (bytes32):
    return ("")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vyper does not have a concept of `None`; instead every type has a default value. For the `bytes32` type that is `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.

You can generate this initial value using `empty()`, e.g.

```
empty_bytes32_var: bytes32 = empty(bytes32)
```

ref: https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/stable/types.html#initial-values

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [initial value of a bytes32](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/stable/types.html?highlight=bytes32#initial-values), which is just `EMPTY_BYTES32`

```py
@external
def return_empty() -> (bytes32):
    return (EMPTY_BYTES32)
```

Comment: UserWarning: EMPTY_BYTES32 is deprecated. Please use `empty(bytes32)` instead.